# mat-tree meets css grid

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material

How can I break down a looooooooooooooong checkbox tree into a more consumable grid layout?

The problem is that there is no grouping wrapper only some padding that indicates group association.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnhvbk?file=app/tree-checklist-example.ts)

May example seems to destroy the functioning of the tree ... however this is more of a `styling - issue`.

How can I make the first case `"look and feel"` like the seconds one?

styling on `mat-tree`

- `style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's impossible to achieve such behavior for a flat tree, like that one in your example. But, you can create a nested tree using `mat-nested-tree-node`. Take a look at *"Tree with nested nodes"* example in the mat tree [examples section](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples). StackBlitz [implementation](https://stackblitz.com/angular/earqaagjdamd?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.html) is also available.